# I think I need Parallel.For to speed this nest up... But how?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, nested-loops, parallel.foreach

I'm building a function to loop through a list of baseball players to create every possible combination of lineups.

I have lists of players for each position. Ie, Pitcher, Catcher, 1st-Base etc...

The challenge is that there is be billions of combinations, so it is a slow process.  I've been reading about using System.Threading to do for loops in parallel but I don't have experience with this at a basic level, and the examples that I can find look a lot simpler (generally demonstrate one nested loop), and I'm having trouble understanding how to apply it with multiple nested loops.

At the inner most nested loop is where I am testing to see if the lineup is valid with the method **validateAndAddToTopLineups** that takes the lineup, a list of valid lineups by reference, and 2 other parameters which are constant limits that are used in determining if the lineups are valid or not.

Should I approach this process differently, or can someone help me with translating this to use the Parallel.For method?

Here is my nested loop, below:

```
for (int p = 0; p < _myPitchers.Count; p++) //For each pitcher
    for (int c = 0; c < _myCatchers.Count; c++) //For each catcher
        for (int b1 = 0; b1 < _myBase1.Count; b1++) //For each 1st base player
            for (int b2 = 0; b2 < _myBase2.Count; b2++) //For each 2nd base player
                for (int b3 = 0; b3 < _myBase3.Count; b3++) //For each 3rd base player
                    for (int ss = 0; ss < _myShortStops.Count; ss++) //For each shortstop
                        for (int oF = 0; oF < OutfielderCombos.Count; oF++) //For each outfielder lineup combination
                        {
                             Lineup testLineup = new Lineup(); //create new lineup
                             testLineup.Pitcher1 = _myPitchers[p];                   //pitcher 1
                             //testLineup.Pitcher1 = _myPitchers[p2];                //pitcher 2
                             testLineup.Catcher = _myCatchers[c];                    //catcher
                             testLineup.Base1 = _myBase1[b1];                        //1st base
                             testLineup.Base2 = _myBase2[b2];                        //2nd base
                             testLineup.Base3 = _myBase3[b3];                        //3rd base
                             testLineup.Shortstop = _myShortStops[ss];               //short stop
                             testLineup.Outfield1 = OutfielderCombos[oF].Outfield1;  //outfielder 1
                             testLineup.Outfield2 = OutfielderCombos[oF].Outfield2;  //outfielder 2
                             testLineup.Outfield3 = OutfielderCombos[oF].Outfield3;  //outfielder 3
                              //determine if lineup is valid, and if so add it to List<Lineup> _ValidLineups
                             validateAndAddToTopLineups(testLineup, ref _ValidLineups, ref SalaryCap, ref SameTeamLimit);
                         }
```

Comment: You have RAM to save the billions of combinations? Or what does `validateAndAddToTopLineups` do with the permutations? If writing to disk/database that will be far slower than your loops (unless a tiny fraction of lineups are actually valid).

Comment: Are you by any chance doing this for fantasy purposes?

Comment: Your maximum benefit from parallelism for a CPU bound task like your loops (aside from what `validateAndAddToTopLineups` does) is bound to the number of CPU cores you can throw at the problem. You could try writing your outer loop as a Parallel.For and leaving the inner loops as normal loops.

Comment: @EricJ,  exactly my thoughts too.  Then I realised the validateAndAddToTopLineups  must be ignoring the invalid lineups.

Comment: why are you creating the testline up and doing all the assignments at the heart of the all the for loops?   Have you considered only creating a new lineup once (before all the Fors) and then after each for make the assignment relative to that for, before then dropping down to the next for and doing the same thing.  Ulitimately then with the oF for only doing the final set of assignments and then the validation.

Comment: @EricJ.  validateAndAddToTopLineups checks to see that there aren't duplicate players on a team, in case a player plays for example 3rd base or outfield, and runs a few other checks.  Then it adds the 'valid' lineup to the list _ValidLineups

Comment: @DavidGreilach I haven't every played fantasy sports yet, but this is an exercise to see what the possibilities are...

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure would that be any different or result in a different number of iterations?  I could do it that way. Do you think it's slower creating the new testLineup every iteration... (probably?)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a Cartesian product there.  It is a huge one, but this is how you'd do it:

```
var enumerator =
    from p in _myPitchers
    from c in _myCatchers
    from b1 in _myBase1
    from b2 in _myBase2
    from b3 in _myBase3
    from ss in _myShortStops
    from of in OutfielderCombos
    select new Lineup
        {
            Pitcher1 = p,
            Catcher = c,
            Base1 = b1,
            Base2 = b2,
            Base3 = b3,
            Shortstop = ss,
            Outfield1 = of.Outfield1,
            Outfield2 = of.Outfield2,
            Outfield3 = of.Outfield3
        };
```

Then you can enumerate through these combos in parallel:

```
var result = enumerator.AsParallel().Where(l => IsValid(l)).ToArray();
```

You'll have to modify your validation to give a boolean `IsValid()` method, but this will traverse your huge set in parallel.

Comment: I hope the OP comes back with some stats that compare the both techniques -- I'm sceptical that parallel processing will help in this situation.

Comment: Here's a question -- would it make a difference to do the validation before the `AsParallel()` rather than afterwards?  I actually don't know.

Comment: Dont be blindly tempted by the desire to go parallel. Coding well in parallel require good knowledge of what is happening under the covers. easy to get wrong - very hard to get right. Do a performance test on the two techniques.  out of interest, I've just a basic test to compare 6 nested loops v's the parallel enumerator and found the nested to execute 11 times faster.  My test is by no means perfect, but it indicates how big the differences can be.

Comment: @PhilB Thanks Phil, yeah I was just looking for ways to make it quicker. Right now I think it would take hours...

Comment: @RobLyndon Going to give this a shot and see how it does! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Will a BlockingCollection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx help you? Outside your loop create the collection and a set of tasks that are trying to pull an entry from the collection.  Each task should wait until a task is available, run it, then wait for another.  At your call to validateAndAddToTopLineups you would try to add a task.  You will be able to add tasks up to your BlockingCollection limit.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx.  I hope you win.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I guess it would allow to run validateAndAddToTopLineups while the loop is running. So that validateAndAddToTopLineups at least wouldn't be waiting for the next valid lineup.

Comment: I might split Validate and Add into 2 separate tasks, possibly with separate Queues too.  Then you have some finer grain control over how much parallelism you want at the expense of a bit more coding complexity.  Sometimes though a bit more code can make your algo faster.  Probably not the case here though.  But it is an alternative which was your original question.

Comment: This BlockingCollection seems to be a good way to go for me. I've split it into a validation task, and valid items are passed to a blocking collection.  Then a task pulls items from the blocking collection and adds them to the top lineups array.

Comment: I did run into a different issue trying to create unique combinations of outfielders for my OutfielderCombos list.  The method I used generates non unique combinations.  How do I take a list of all outfielders and generate combinations, where outfield position doesn't matter?  Ie John, Mark, Bob in Outfield1, Outfield2, Outfield 3, without generating Mark, John, Bob in Outfield 1, Outfield 2, Outfield 3.  These are the same to me, so I'm causing a lot more iterations than I need to...

Comment: i've tried both the blocking collection and the enumerator approaches.  i havent been able to compare or benchmark them to my original non threaded loops because ive come to realize there are just wayyyy to many iterations to do here.  i even tried it on a Microsoft Azure virtual machine with 8 cores and it still is too many iterations.  i calculated the number of iterations and assigned to a Uint64 and the number is incomprehensible. 18,446,744,071,628,531,200 for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Both the blocking collection and the enumerator approaches are great, meaning I at least got them to work.

I wasn't able to compare or benchmark them to my original single thread nested loops because I've come to realize there are just wayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy*(y)^yy to many iterations to do here.  I even tried it on a speedy Azure virtual machine with 8 cores and it's still brutal.

I calculated the number of iterations, assigned to a Uint64 and the number is incomprehensible. 18,446,744,071,628,531,200 or 18 quintillion! Slightly more than the original billions I was thinking.

Thanks for the help and the ideas, the blocking collections are neato, and really quite simple to implement!

if anyone has a suggestion as to how to pare down my problem to a manageable size or approach it differently let me know!

**...Update...
FYI:  I was able to solve this with a linear optimization algorithm.  I used 
[lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/index.htm) which can be used in any programming IDE or language.  It found the optimal solution in less than a second!**

Comment: If you have multiple machines you can assign 1 machine to each pitcher.  If you have even more machines you can assign 1 machine to each catcher.  This assumes the data is equally accessible to every individual machine.  The complexity will increase because you would need something to orchestrate all of the result but this particular task would scale almost linearly for every machine you can add.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns That's a good point, and certainly an option with cloud virtual machines.  I found another post [HERE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538602/baseball-roster-optimization) that suggests grouping the players into sets, so the number of combos is more managable, and then refining those sets to get to the solution...  I'm reading up on a few libraries that have classes for optimization, such as [DotNumerics](http://www.dotnumerics.com).